# Few controls from Angular material not visible in chrome versions above 68.x.x.x

Tags: angular, google-chrome

Few controls from Angular material are not visible in chrome versions above 68.x.x.x. Angular material like mat-form-field, matInput, mat-error, mat-autocomplete inside form are not visible.

Operating system -windows 10
Package.json :- few details-

```
{
  "name": "my-first-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.7",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="view">
  <div mat-dialog-title>
    {{Title}}
    <button mat-button [matTooltipShowDelay]="500" matTooltip="Close dialog" type="button" (click)="close()" class="material-icons close closeOrGoBackButton">close</button>
  </div>

  <table class="class1">
    <form [formGroup]="FormGroup1" (ngSubmit)="isExisting ? reshcedule() : book()">
      <tr *ngIf="isExist`enter code here`ingAppointment">
        <td colspan="2">
          <h3> {{FormGroup1.get('type').value.Name}} </h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="!isExistingAppointment">
        <td>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput id="type" type="text" placeholder="type" formControlName="type" [matAutocomplete]="autoService">
            <mat-error *ngIf="FormGroup1.get('type') && FormGroup1.get('type').hasError('required')">
              Select the required type.
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="FormGroup1.get('type') && FormGroup1.get('type').hasError('validatetype')">
              Select type from list.
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="FormGroup1.get('type') && FormGroup1.get('type').hasError('500005')">
              {{getBusinessRuleErrorMessage('500005')}}
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="FormGroup1.get('type') && FormGroup1.get('type').hasError('typeId')">
              <span *ngFor="let inputError of getInputValidationErrorMessages('typeId')">
                                {{inputError}}<br/>
                            </span>
            </mat-error>
            <mat-autocomplete [displayWith]="displaySelectedtype" #autoService="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="change($event,type.Id)" *ngFor="let type of filteredtypes | async" [value]="type">
                {{type.Name}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
        <td><button mat-button [matTooltipShowDelay]="500" matTooltip="Reset" type="button" (click)="reset()" class="resetMdAutoComplete"><img class="img" /></button></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is the angular material component used in the angular app.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show some code you're using for getting this error ?

Comment: Thanks @Zooly for your help.

Comment: @Zooly can you see whats wrong with the angular material. It is working with chrome version 68 and below versions.